# data type mismatch in criteria expression while update

Tags: c#

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\PMEnterprise.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=???????");    
try
{
    string query;
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmdupdate = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdupdate.Connection = conn;
    query = "UPDATE Print_Cash_Entry_Credit SET Token_No = '" + txttoken.Text + "', Entry_Date = '" + dtpdate.Text + "', Sender_Name = '" + txtSender.Text + "', Center_Name = '" + txtcenter.Text + "', Money_Amount = '" + txtmoney.Text + "', Receiver_Name = '" + txtReceiver.Text + "', Mob_No = '" + txtmono.Text + "', PM_Amount_Com='0', Company_Amount_Com = '0' WHERE ID = '1'"; 
    cmdupdate.CommandText = query;
    cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Updated!");
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
}
```

here screenshot for Table structure..

I'm getting "data type mismatch in criteria expression" Error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv9g6.png

Comment: It might be all those values are passed as string.  Use SQL parameters...and do research - this comes up several times a week

Comment: Because you are using number type for Token_No  in your table while trying to pass a text (string type) via the query. This type of trivial question should not be here. Please use your due diligence while coding and use the exception message as a hint to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID is a number but you are passing in a string ('ID').

Try this:

...WHERE ID = 1"

Answer (score 0):

Just first thing, I see you using ' ' to assign to a DataType => Number.

Like Plutonix said, make sure to research how you structure your query so that you pass the data types correctly.